# Binding ComboBoxItem Value Inside of a Setter Property in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In my wpf application I have a ComboBox which I want to have the ability to disable the selection of items in the drop-down programmatically. The issue that I am having is that the binding **ComboBoxItemIsEnabled** is not working as expected inside the setter. If remove the binding and use either True or False it works as expected.

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ConfigItems.Result}"  
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    IsEditable="True"
    FontSize="14"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    IsTextSearchEnabled="False" 
    Text="{Binding Path=ConfigItem,
           UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, 
           TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}}"
    b:ComboBoxBehaviors.OnButtonPress="True">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding ComboBoxItemIsEnabled}" />
         </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

**C#**

```
private string _comboBoxItemIsEnabled = "True";

public string ComboBoxItemIsEnabled
{
    get
    {
        return this._comboBoxItemIsEnabled;
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetProperty(ref this._comboBoxItemIsEnabled, value);
    }
}

public async Task<ConfigItem[]> LoadConfigItemsAsync(string partialName)
{
    try
    {
        if (partialName.Length >= 5)
        {
            this.ComboBoxItemIsEnabled = "True";
            return await this._Service.GetConfigItemsAsync(partialName);
        }
        this.ComboBoxItemIsEnabled = "False";
        return new[] { new ConfigItem("Minimum of 5 characters required", null)};
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        this.ComboBoxItemIsEnabled = "False";
        return new[] { new ConfigItem("No results found", null) };
    }
}
```

I also get the the following error from the debug console when the ComboBoxIsEnabled is being set.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ComboBoxItemIsEnabled' property not found on 'object' ''ConfigItem' (HashCode=56037929)'. BindingExpression:Path=ComboBoxItemIsEnabled; DataItem='ConfigItem' (HashCode=56037929); target element is 'ComboBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')
```

I am using the same mvvm method to target an **IsEnabled** property for a button else where without an issue. The only difference I can see in the issue above is that I am setting the property within a setter instead.

Many thanks for any wisdom you can part with on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Try with bool instead of string

Comment: @sTrenat Thanks for the reply, I will definitely give a go. I had thought it may be the cause but dismissed it as a different control didn't require me to do it.

Comment: If anyone else want's to down vote my question please leave a comment for their reason why. It seems awfully pointless to do so and I don't really see whats wrong with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much procrastinating and smashing my head against the keyboard I managed to come to a solution. As it turns out I needed to set the Relative source for the binding. Because I didn't define the DataContext for my solution, every time I pressed a character in the combobox the ItemSource was updated. This meant the ComboBoxItemIsEnabled binding couldn't be found giving me the error above. Below is my updated code, I have added **DataContext** in front of my binding and added **RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}** behind it.

Below is my final code.

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding DataContext.ComboBoxItemIsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}" />
     </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```